Running Parallel Query in JDBC Aurora mysql
I am currently writing a simple application using Java 8. Essentially, I am trying to run parallel queries in my application. By default, I can run it in MySQL client with aurora_pq_force=ON and aurora_parallel_query=ON enabled.
I've tried to pass the session variables in the JDBC connection string like this:
jdbc:mysql://10.10.12.238:3306?sessionVariables=aurora_pq_force=ON,aurora_parallel_query=ON

Then I tried to execute SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table_name. Before that, my code returns an EXPLAIN for that query. However, the result shows that the query is not working with Aurora Parallel Query.
C:\Users\tunm12\Desktop\BNH\app - roc - count>java -jar app\comparator-2.0.jar --properties-file conf\application.properties --mode query --db-type dst --query "select count(*) from PAYMENT_ORDER.PMT_ORDER use index()" 

INFO  2024-06-20 18:39:06.446 ReaderServiceImpl Load properties successful 

INFO  2024-06-20 18:39:06.646 ReaderServiceImpl Load properties successful 
##Here is explain result
id 1 

select_type SIMPLE 

table PMT_ORDER 

partitions p202312,p202401,p202402,p202403,p202404,p202405,p202406,p202407,p202408,p202409,p202410,p202411,p202412,p202501,p202502,p202503,p202504,p202505,p202506,p202507,p202508,p202509,p202510,p202511,p202512,PMAX 

type ALL 

possible_keys null 

key null 

key_len null 

ref null 

rows 313376140 

filtered 100.0 

Extra null 

Can anyone help me with this issue?
Thank you.

Feel free to adjust any details as needed.
Running parallel query with jdbc 8.4

Amazon aurora is not mysql, only highly compatible with it. For example, if you tried to connect to a mysql with your connection string, you would get an error as those parameters do not exist in mysql.

Hi @Shadow, I just using the same jdbc connection string to heimdall proxy and it works . So i think the connection string it not a problem

I did not write the connection parameters were an issue for you. I made the case that you mistakenly mapped the question to mysql.
